# Adjective, adjective noun vs. Adjective, adjective noun

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Enxample:

> The voice was **low, boyish, like** that of an elementary school
> student.
>
> The voice was **low, boyish like** that of an elementary school
> student.

What's the correct punctuation and why?

Comment: Both are possible - it just depends on whether ***like that of an elementary school student*** is supposed to refer to *just* the fact of the voice being "boyish", OR to both qualities ("low" ***and*** "boyish"). If both, include the comma, otherwise the lack of a pause before ***like*** means we restrict the scope of that clause to just the one immediately preceding term. I can't for the life of me understand why an *elementary* pupil's voice would be "low" though - I'd have though we must be talking about a younger child, hence one with a ***high-pitched*** voice. But I'm not the author! :)